# PHP MySQL Equivalent MsSQL Functions

Tags: php, sql-server

I am currently working on a project that requires a connection to a MsSQL database. Although I have never used MsSQL, I am a little familiar with how it works and differs from MySQL. However, I am unfamiliar with the integration of PHP and MsSQL. I have written a class for MySQL and am hoping to convert this class to MsSQL. So far all is good, but I have run into 2 functions that are not present in the predefined PHP library. These being:

1. mysql_real_escape_string
2. mysql_field_flags

Does anybody know of somewhere that shows how to recreate these equivalent functions for MsSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to use `parameterised queries` and prepared statements with [PDO library](http://au.php.net/pdo).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have now had a chance to research into PDO a little more and it is definitely the way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed this further and concluded that I will need to rewrite these functions myself. When I have done, I will post them up here for reference purposes.

**UPDATE**

More research has shown that the answer supplied by Viswanathan Iyer, is in fact correct. For connecting to a MsSQL database, the most effective and efficient way is to use the PDO library supplied by PHP